# Is there any other way to parse the Excel file with irregular tables?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, parsing

I used to use `pandas` to parse the Excel file and it worked pretty well when the data follows a table format. But recently I got a new data look like this:

[image]

When I use `pandas` to read the Excel file, it would read the entire spreadsheet instead of the tables (week by week). My idea now is to reorganize the tables.

For example, when I read the column B from *row 10* to *row 25*, if I encounter the value equals to "**% Rejection**", then it will move right to read the percentage of each day (for seven times) and create a new table I want.

However, it feels like not quite efficient. Therefore, I'm curious if there is any other way to parse the data. Any recommendation would be great. Thank you.

Edit:
I wonder if I can parse the Excel file to a table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: what is the specific problem you're having? Can you provide a [mcve]? what does pandas give you? what do you expect/want instead?

Comment: Looks like you what to swap the columns and rows.  What about COM1 and COM3, aren't they included in the total too?  I believe there are some add-ins that can do something similar; can be done with VBA too.